# SED inserting a blank line below a line

Tags: sed

I want to add a black line below a line ending in a period.
I have `sed '/ REGEX goes here/G'`  I'm not sure how to replace the regex to except a period as expression to look for.

I want to add a blank line below each sentence here's an example of some text I would want to use the sed shell script on.

```
Line one.
The second line.
The third.
This is line four.
five.
This is the sixth sentence.
This is line seven.
Eighth and last.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following `sed`

```
sed 's/\.$/.\n/' file
```

**EDIT** (after comments of *@Jotne*)

If you have any spaces after `.` at the end of line, adding `\s*` would be safe.

```
sed 's/\.\s*$/.\n/' file
```

Comment: Does not work in my Ubuntu 12.04, not sure why. (prints all line)

Comment: @Jotne surprising. worked for me, running RHEL5. Are there any space after dot? Can you please try `sed 's/\.\s*$/.\n/' file`?

Comment: This did work, I made a test file in nano, and did not add space after the `.`  It may be my system making some strange things.

Comment: @Jotne thanks for your confirmation. Added that alternate answer to solution.

Comment: @fedorqui Even though Jotne's problem may not be real but having spaces at the end of a line is not un-common, hence was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to replace the regex to except a period as expression
>   to look for.

You can say:

```
sed '/\.$/G' filename
```

Escape the `.` so as to match a literal `.`; the anchor `$` ensures that the matched `.` was at the end of line.